# Is it a bad practice to display body on window.onload?

Tags: html, css

My document is moving a lot when it's loading (even though it takes < 1 second), it's ugly.

**Is it, for any reason, a bad practice to do this?**

```
<body style="display:none";>
...
<script>window.onload = function() { $('body').css('display', 'block'); }</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a little bit opinion based but there is a circumstance where it's considera bad practice: in progressive enhancement. In this web design strategy the content goes first in order to guarantee that, even i users that don't have JavaScript activated can access the content. It's a recommendation and you can read more about it here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

Comment: As a comment to that,I think it's a better practice to have a loading image that covers the entire page and disappears when the content kiddo loads

Comment: @Dnacht, that has the same problem: if JavaScript disabled. However I personally don't care about users with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: @PoulBak yes, it has the same problem, I meant to comment this in MadPapo answer. Yes, if your app requires javascript to work there is no point to worry about javascript disabled, in fact one of the criticism and responses of progressive enhancement is that its not always possible to offer script free content. so, great appointment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only CSS rules to set dimensions to elements inside, the problem could be only in performance side

If you are using JavaScript to set static dimensions (px) to elements inside (proportionated to parent), your app will not work (the width of a `div` is 0 while it is `display:none`)

By the way, this practice involve in performance problem.This because the redraw of the entire body is called on body onload (and depending on CPU) could be heavy.

The progressive rendering during page load is ensuring that slow CPU render the page in acceptable time

Comment: This is a good point, if the body is not displayed some widths and heights won't calculate properly if you are not using the right units.

Comment: Not the right units. But if you read from JS the dimension of an element to apply a  proportioned width to an element inside it, the width of the parent element will be 0 until it is shown